# rc params for pairplot axis and legend's label color

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Im using sns pairplot in a dark background,
So want to set the axis and legend's label color to white
I couldn't find any appropriate function that does this job, how do i change the color?

```
import seaborn as sns 
DATA=sns.load_dataset("tips")           
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                 
plt.figure()      
sns.set_style(style="white")
              
ax=sns.pairplot(data=DATA, 
palette="viridis",hue="tip")


plt.savefig('image.png',transparent=True)
```

Image
[image]

Comment: See https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/style_sheets/dark_background.html  `plt.style.use('dark_background')`

Answer (score 0):

The params you're looking for are `legend.labelcolor` and `axes.labelcolor` , see [The default matplotlibrc file](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#the-default-matplotlibrc-file):

```
with plt.matplotlib.rc_context({'legend.labelcolor': 'w', 'axes.labelcolor': 'w'}):            
    ax=sns.pairplot(data=DATA, palette="viridis",hue="tip")
```